# Get parent name

Tags: winforms, powershell, event-handling

With what method or variable can I find out the name of the parent object in this example? That is, during the event of hovering the mouse over the first button, get the name $GetParentName = `"Button01"`, second $GetParentName = `"Button02"`, third $GetParentName = `"Button03"`. $GetParentName is `[string]`.

If instead of the variable `$GetParentName` to apply `$This`, then the variable `$This` allows you to get the values of the object, but does not get the name of the object. But how to get the name of the object? Thanks

***Edited:*** without using $This.Name.

```
$A = @{

    Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterParent' }

    Button01 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 0 }
    Button02 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 30 }
    Button03 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 60 }
}

$Script = { Write-host $GetParentName }

1..3 | % {

    $A["Button0$_"].Add_MouseEnter($Script)

    $A.Main.Controls.Add($A["Button0$_"])
}

[void]$A.Main.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Theo points out [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60227143/45375), you need to **name your button objects by assigning to their `.Name` property**.

To avoid naming your buttons *twice* - once as a property name in your hashtable, and again via the `.Name` property - you can **create the buttons as an *array***, which simplifies the solution overall:

```
$A = @{

    Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterParent' }

    # Create an *array* of buttons
    Buttons = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 0; Name = 'Button1' },
              [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 30; Name = 'Button2' },
              [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 60; Name = 'Button3' }
}

# Print the name of the button being moused over.
$Script = { $this.Name | Out-Host }

# Attach the event-handler script block to each button.
$A.Buttons | % {

    $_.Add_MouseEnter($Script)

}

# Add the buttons to the form.
$A.Main.Controls.AddRange($A.Buttons)

$null = $A.Main.ShowDialog()
```

---

**If you want to avoid assigning to the `.Name` property**, you can use the following approach:

**Use PowerShell's ETS (Extended Type System) to add** the key of the hashtable entry in which each button is stored as **a *custom property*** (a `NoteProperty` instance member), using `Add-Member`, which the event-handler script can query:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$A = @{

    Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterParent' }

    Button01 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 0 }
    Button02 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 30 }
    Button03 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 60 }
}

$Script = {
    # Access the custom .CustomParent property added to each button instance below.
    Write-Host $this.CustomParent
}

1..3 | % {

    $key = "Button0$_"
    $btn = $A[$key]
    # Add a .CustomParent NoteProperty member to the button object
    # storing the key of the hashtable entry in which that button is stored.
    $btn | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers @{ CustomParent = $key }

    $btn.Add_MouseEnter($Script)

    $A.Main.Controls.Add($btn)
}

[void]$A.Main.ShowDialog()
```

---

As for why PowerShell doesn't - and shouldn't - provide an automatic (built in) variable such as `$GetParentName` to support this scenario:

There are two *unrelated* worlds involved in this scenario:

- PowerShell variables
- The .NET types from the `System.Windows.Forms` namespace (WinForms)

WinForms is language-agnostic - any .NET language can use it; all it knows about is how instance of its types are nested at runtime and how to raise appropriate .NET events, typically in response to user events.

The *source object* of an event, as reported by WinForms, is surfaced as `$this` in a PowerShell script block acting as a .NET event delegate invoked directly by WinForms.

WinForms (rightfully) has no knowledge of what data structure or variable on the PowerShell side the event-originating object is stored in.

Even on the PowerShell side this is completely at your discretion - you could have chosen individual variables, for instance, or an array, as shown above, so there is *no general pattern* here that an automatic variable could support.

In the case at hand, PowerShell itself has no way of knowing that your `$Script` block happens to be indirectly associated with a button instance *incidentally stored in a hashtable entry*.

Comment: Many thanks! This is a universal option. You once again helped. I thought a couple of hours ago on whether it is possible to add new properties to an object. And I found ```Add-Member``` in the documentation. Now your example has helped me understand this with an example.

Comment: Glad to hear it was helpful, @КириллЗацепин. I initially wasn't sure if the custom properties would survive passing through .NET APIs, but they do, because PowerShell (since v3) goes out of its way to preserve them.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the `.Name` property for the button controls if you want to get their names inside the MouseEnter script:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$A = @{

    Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterParent' }

    Button01 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 0  ; Name = 'Button01'}
    Button02 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 30 ; Name = 'Button02'}
    Button03 = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = 60 ; Name = 'Button03'}
}

$Script = { Write-host $this.Name }

1..3 | ForEach-Object {

    $A["Button0$_"].Add_MouseEnter($Script)

    $A.Main.Controls.Add($A["Button0$_"])
}

[void]$A.Main.ShowDialog()

$A.Main.Dispose()
```

---

**Edit**

Creating and naming the buttons inside the `ForEach-Object` loop could save you typing the name for each button:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$A = @{
    Main = [System.Windows.Forms.Form] @{ StartPosition = 'CenterParent' }
}

$Script = { Write-host $this.Name }

1..3 | ForEach-Object {
    $A["Button0$_"] = [System.Windows.Forms.Button] @{ Top = ($_ -1) * 30 ; Name = "Button0$_"}
    $A["Button0$_"].Add_MouseEnter($Script)

    $A.Main.Controls.Add($A["Button0$_"])
}

[void]$A.Main.ShowDialog()

$A.Main.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, at the moment I'm doing it. I write the name in the Name. And then I use it ```$This.Name```. But this is not always convenient. I hope there is another way.

Comment: @КириллЗацепин I have added shorter code that also doesn't need typing the name for each button yourself.

Comment: Thanks. I edid added a question to. How to find out the name of an object without using the $This.Name.